# ServiceKnownTypeAttribute doesn't pop up in WSDL

Tags: wcf, web-services, .net-3.5, serviceknowntype

I have an service Interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Models.ArticleImage))]
public interface IPhotoManagementService
{
    [OperationContract]
    bool Login(string username, string password);

    [OperationContract]
    bool IsLoggedIn();

    [OperationContract]
    void UpdateImage(string articleID, string selectedImage);
}
```

As you can see I specify a typeof(Models.ArticleImage) on my ServiceContract.

So building the WSDL of this service should cause ArticleImage to pop up in the WSDL. Unfortunarly this doesn't happen at all. Why is that?

ArticleImage has DataContract on it. And when I return an ArticleImage in my interface, then the WSDL does pick up ArticleImage.

Edit: it doesn't even pop up in the service reference in the consuming project!

---

This is the result of a lot of testing:

- The model I'm trying to add is a LINQ to SQL model.
- When I add a normal model with ServiceKnownType it works.
- When I use my LINQ to SQL entities in my Interface it works.
- When I add my LINQ to SQL entity through ServiceKnownType it doesn't pop up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would it need to? Where does your service expose something that could *possibly* be an `ArticleImage`?

Re your comment; when using `[ServiceKnownType]`, the extra trype is still exposed in the "mex" (consumed via "svcutil") - but not by the WSDL. Are you using a WCF client? It should appear (I've just checked... it did). In general, though, returning vague data from a web-service isn't a great idea... sub-types, sure! `Dictionary<string,ArticleImage>`  or even `Dictionary<string,SomeBaseType>` (with `[KnownType]` etc), fine! But `object`, `HashTable`, etc - aren't a good idea (IMO).

You might also just return a **list** of your type (`List<ArticleImage>`) which will work in all scenarios (and be easy for WSDL etc); and let the client make the dictionary at their end.

---

With regards to LINQ-to-SQL; objects for "mex" need to be decorated with `[DataContract]` / `[DataMember]`. You can do this in the designed by toggling the "serialization" property for the dbml. With this set (Serialization Mode = Unidirectional), it should work. To be honest, though, I think you be better-off just adding a dummy method that makes the type explicit on the API.

Comment: Let's say I return an HashTable of ArticleImage?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio to consume the WCF Service (Add Service Reference).

Unfortunately it doesn't pop up at all.

Comment: That worked for me... it generated: `[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "3.0.0.0")]
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="ArticleImage", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Models")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    public partial class ArticleImage ` etc...

Comment: Indeed, that works for me too. The problem is that the 'Model' I'm trying to include is actually a Linq to SQL Object.

Answer (score 1):

Only types used as input/output parameters of service contract operations are published in the WSDL.

Comment: That's where ServiceKnownType should come in handy! And it doesn't work.

Comment: No, `ServiceKnownTypeAttribute` is used to indicate possible derived types of some base type that one of your service operations expose. This is not your case. In the example you provided `string` and `bool` are the only types.